# how to programmatically add XmlNode to an XmlNodeList

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have an XmlNodeList of products whose values are put into a table. Now I want to add a new XmlNode to the list when a certain product is found so that in the same loop the new products is treated the same as the items that are originally in the file. This way the structire of the function does not need to change, just add an extra node that is processed next.
But an XmlNode is an abstract class and I cant figure out how to create the new node programatically. Is this possible?

```
XmlNodeList list = productsXml.SelectNodes("/portfolio/products/product");

for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
  XmlNode node = list[i];

  if (node.Attributes["name"].InnertText.StartsWith("PB_"))
  {
    XmlNode newNode = ????
    list.InsertAfter(???, node);
  }

  insertIntoTable(node);
}
```

Comment: `productsXml.CreateElement("newNode")`?

Comment: I don't have time for a full example right now, but see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87274khy.aspx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`XmlDocument` is the factory for its nodes so you have to do this:

```
XmlNode newNode = document.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "product", "");
```

Or its shortcut:

```
XmlNode newNode = document.CreateElement("product");
```

Then to add newly created node to its parent:

```
node.ParentNode.AppendChild(newNode);
```

If added node must be processed then you have to do it explicitly: node list is a snapshot of nodes that matched search condition then it won't be dynamically updated. Simply call `insertIntoTable()` for added node:

```
insertIntoTable(node.ParentNode.AppendChild(newNode));
```

If your code is much different you may need little bit of refactoring to make this process a two step batch (first search for nodes to add and then process them all). Of course you may even follow a completely different approach (for example copying nodes from `XmlNodeList` to a List and then adding them to both lists).

Assuming this is enough (and you do not need refactoring) let's put everything together:

```
foreach (var node in productsXml.SelectNodes("/portfolio/products/product"))
{
  if (node.Attributes["name"].InnertText.StartsWith("PB_"))
  {
    XmlNode newNode = document.CreateElement("product");
    insertIntoTable(node.ParentNode.AppendChild(newNode));
  }

  // Move this before previous IF in case it must be processed
  // before added node
  insertIntoTable(node);
}
```

### Refactoring

Refactoring time (and if you have a 200 lines function you really need it, much more than what I present here). First approach even if not very efficient:

```
var list = productsXml
    .SelectNodes("/portfolio/products/product")
    .Cast<XmlNode>();
    .Where(x.Attributes["name"].InnertText.StartsWith("PB_"));

foreach (var node in list)
    node.ParentNode.AppendChild(document.CreateElement("product"));

foreach (var node in productsXml.SelectNodes("/portfolio/products/product"))
    insertIntoTable(node); // Or your real code
```

If you do not like a two passes approach you may use `ToList()` like this:

```
var list = productsXml
    .SelectNodes("/portfolio/products/product")
    .Cast<XmlNode>()
    .ToList();

for (int i=0; i < list.Count; ++i)
{
    var node = list[i];

    if (node.Attributes["name"].InnertText.StartsWith("PB_"))
      list.Add(node.ParentNode.AppendChild(document.CreateElement("product"))));

    insertIntoTable(node);
}
```

Please note that in second example the use of `for` instead of `foreach` is mandatory because you change the collection within the loop. Note that you may even keep your original `XmlNodeList` object in place...

Comment: How will this cause the new node to be "processed next"?

Comment: @musefan in that code he doesn't need to process his own added nodes because he's iterating the list with the purpose to add new nodes.

Comment: Then why did the OP explicit state "add an extra node that is processed next", I agree there is no need to process the node next as they should have control over it before adding it anyway. There is also no mention of them wanting to add the node to the original document, which you have suggested... it may just be the question is poorly written, or the OP doesn't really understand what they are asking

Comment: @musefan you may be right, I assumed few things about his requirements. If it doesn't work for him I suppose he'll clarify (or maybe not...)

Comment: @ServéLaurijssen updated my answer. I didn't see you have to process added nodes too.

Comment: Im afraid the real function is 200 lines so a lot of refactoring would be involved, adding a node and process it in the loop somewhere sounded so good :)

Comment: @ServéLaurijssen I added a section about Refactoring. It's **always** pretty easy (see last two examples) but...IMO if you have a function with 200 lines of code...you **really** need it and much more in deep than this...

Answer (score 2):

You can't create an XmlNode directly, but only the subtypes (e.g. elements) by using one of the Create* methods of the parent [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). E.g. if you want to create a new element:

```
XmlElement el = doc.CreateElement("elementName");
node.ParentNode.InsertAfter(el, node);
```

Please note that this will not add the element to the XmlNodeList list so the node won't be processed. All necessary processing of the node should therefore be done right when adding the node.

Comment: not sure why this is down voted, it is better then the other answer as it actually inserts the node in the correct place

Comment: InsertAfter throws "the reference node is not a child of this node", I'll go for the node.ParentNode.AppendChild as it doesnt matter when it is processed as long as it is

Comment: @ServéLaurijssen: using `node.ParentNode.AppendChild` will never allow the node to be processed within your for loop. Do you mean processing it somewhere else, like after the for loop?

Comment: you're right, found that out now too but InsertAfter throws the exception

Comment: Looks like XmlNodeList does not support InsertAfter, so you have to use node.ParentNode.InsertAfter (edited my answer to reflect this). However, this does not add the node to the XmlNodeList list so it won't be processed. Maybe you need to change the approach so that you loop over the document or over the children parent item "products" (depends on whether SelectNodes reduces the number of nodes significantly). A sample of your Xml document would be good in order to answer this.

Comment: @Markus: That last comment of yours should be part of your answer, it is important to state that adding a node using `ParentNode` will not effect the items iterated in the loop

Comment: @musefan: Thanks for the hint. I edited the answer accordingly.