# How do i add a new row to an xml file existing id number?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, datagridview

How do i add a new row to an xmlfile existing id number?

I want to be able to add a new row to my xml file, but using the same id from the file. My xml files have three rows and I want to add rows until I get tired. this is what is mean;

1. I have an xml file.
2. I have loaded the xmlfile to the datagridview
3. File loaded to the datagridview with current data.
4. The user must continue with capturing new rows or unlimited rows.
5. After all the changes it must goes to the file.

Everything is working, reading, writing and editing the current cell from three rows and saving. I want to be able to add a new rows with these three ID's which are:

```
  name="model"
  name="year"
  name="color"
```

If I add another row it throws an error

XML file:

```
<root>  
  <dealer name="model">
    <number>Hashback</number>
  </dealer>
  <dealer name="year">
    <year>2008</year>
  </dealer>
  <dealer name="color">
    <color>black</color>
  </dealer>
 </root>
```

My code:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(FilePath);
    XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
    XmlNodeList CnodesList = root.SelectNodes("descendant::dealer");

    string Tag = string.Empty;
    int iTotalRowCount = Gridview_Output.Rows.Count - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < iTotalRowCount; i++)
    {
        Tag = "";
        string name = Gridview_Output.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        if (Gridview_Output.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString().Length > 0)
        {
            Tag = Gridview_Output.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        }
        if (Gridview_Output.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString().Length > 0)
        {
            Tag = Gridview_Output.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        }
        if (Gridview_Output.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString().Length > 0)
        {
            Tag = Gridview_Output.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        }

        XmlAttributeCollection xxxx = CnodesList[i].Attributes;
        for (int x = 0; x < xxxx.Count; x++)
        {
            if (xxxx[x].Value.ToString().Contains(name))
            {
                XmlNodeList Elements = CnodesList[i].ChildNodes;
                for (int z = 0; z < Elements.Count; z++)
                {
                    if (Elements[z].Name == "number")
                    {
                        Elements[z].InnerXml = Tag;
                    }
                    if (Elements[z].Name == "year")
                    {
                        Elements[z].InnerXml = Tag;
                    }
                    if (Elements[z].Name == "color")
                    {
                        Elements[z].InnerXml = Tag;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    doc.Save(FilePath);
}
```

Comment: hi maybe you find your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808150/how-to-programmatically-add-xmlnode-to-an-xmlnodelist

Comment: didn't help. i tried this

Comment: What is the exception ?

Comment: And you should use System.linq.xml