# How to add a XML node in a XmlNodeList

Tags: c#, xml

I have a XmlNodeList nl and a XmlNode n.  Could someone please tell how I can insert the node "n" in specific index  in the list "nl" ?

Thanks!

Comment: As you can see [in the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodelist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), you can't. Why don't you zoom out a bit and explain what you're actually trying to do here?

Comment: Are you sure you are wanting to add it to an arbitrary `XmlNodeList` or to an `XmlDocument` that you have already extracted an `XmlNodeList` from?  Please can you provide a code sample of what you have and we can help.

Comment: it looks that there is no function that can do that :(
 I'm basically just trying to reorder some Nodes in a Xml file. For example :

```xml
<books>
<book id="12_AE"> </book>
<book id="36_FD"> </book>
<book id="55_DL"> </book>
<book id="20_NF"> </book >
<books>
```


I would like to change it to:

```xml
 <books>
<book id="55_DL"> </book>
<book id="20_NF"> </book>
<book id="36_FD"> </book>
<book id="12_AE"> </book>
 </books>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to that post : [how to programmatically add XmlNode to an XmlNodeList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808150/how-to-programmatically-add-xmlnode-to-an-xmlnodelist) you can't.

Try something like this :

```
XmlNode n1;
XmlNode n2;
n1.ParentNode.AppendChild(n2);
```